# Get function from specialized plot

Tags: plotting, evaluation, output-formatting

I have generated a 3D plot using a specialized plotting function (in this case, `SmoothHistogram3D`). I would like to extract the function shown in this plot (even if it ends up being something like an `InterpolatingFunction`), so that I can find values, take derivatives, plot slices, etc. Is there any way to do this without manually generating the function outside of the specialized plotting function? Alternatively, is there a way to stop the specialized plotting function after it calculates the `InterpolatingFunction` (or equivalent), but before it plots it?

Answer (score 3):

`SmoothHistogram3D` is based on `SmoothKernelDistribution`, which wrapped in `PDF` will give you your function:

```
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.75], 10];
dis = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];
Plot3D[PDF[dis, {x, y}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

For other cases use `Interpolation` to get `InterpolatingFunction`.